# A constructive proof that regular languages are closed under division

Tags: automata, regular-language

The claim in the title is described [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/34006/are-regular-languages-closed-under-division), along with a non constructive proof.

Here is the claim:

> For languages $A$ and $B$ define $A \div B = \{x \in \Sigma^{\ast} : xy \in A 
>  \text{ for all } y \in B\}$. 
>   If $R$ is regular and $L$ is any
>   language, is it always the case that $R\div L$ is regular?

Is there a constructive proof for this claim? Hence, is there a deterministic way to generate a DFA that accepts $R\div L$, given a DFA that accepts $R$?

Comment: Did you read the answer to the question you are referring to?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes, I did. It is not constructive. I understand that we can't hope to construct a DFA for $L$, but I'm not sure why this implies that no constructive proof can be found.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. You would like to have an algorithm which gives as output a DFA accepting $R \div L$. Fine. But was is the input? If you just give $R$, you have no information about $L$, right?

Comment: The input would be a regular language $R$, and a language $ L$. We know that there exists a DFA for $R \div  L $. So we might hope that using the basic properties of a language $L$, we can somehow construct that DFA. If not, we might want to prove why this can't be done algorithmically.

Comment: How do you give $L$?

Comment: Given an alphabet $\Sigma$, $L$ is an arbitrary subset of $\Sigma^*$.

Comment: "The input would be a regular language $R$ and a language $L$". If you want to have $L$ in the input, you need a way to describe it.